# MVC2 : Troubles in edit state with modelstate using a structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, structure, edit, modelstate

I have the following problem. 
I'm using a structure (not a single table) to display my edit page.

When Im submitting my page, (an ascx page), after having filled all the fields, I fill some ModelState.Error (with ModelState.AddModelError)
It is well detected by my code line "if (!ModelState.IsValid) "

However, once the Form is updated (once the line "return" of my Edit(post) is call), not any ModelErrorState are displayed. 
The same code on a form using a single table is working without any problem.

Im almost sure that the problem is coming from the way I reload my structure.

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you put the appropriate Validation helpers on your form?

Comment: Yes. The code is working for the same page, using a table only. Im quite sure the problem is coming from the using of the structure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally found my answer.

I was writing the following line : 
ModelState.AddModelError("MY_DATE_TO_FILL", "Please fill this field");

instead of the following : 
ModelState.AddModelError("MyClass.MY_DATE_TO_FILL", "Please fill this field");

Its working now.